# Where is the best place to post a question about milk?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a health-related site, or food-related site in the Stack Exchange network that would be an appropriate place to ask this question: "Is ALL grade A milk pasteurized by definition"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably post this reasonably on either [cooking.stackexchange.com](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), or on [parenting.stackexchange.com](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/).  I'd guess you'll have better luck on cooking.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about the requirements of "grade A milk". Most likely, that is spelled out in your country's food labeling laws. Your country may also have general pasteurization rules to sell milk at all.

That's a [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) question, not really a cooking question.